# Shemona Ve'esrim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred twenty-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

128 are the days from זמן שמחתנו until מרבין בשמחה (in Israel (where שמ״ע is one day) in a "full" year).

Answer (score 2):

128 years separate the first imprisonment (and release) of a Chabad Rebbe from the last. The first - R' Shneur Zalman of Liadi, released from prison on the 19th of Kislev 5559 (1798); the last - R' Yosef Yitzchak, released from prison on the 12th of Tammuz 5687 (1927).

128 years also separate the passing of the two Chabad Rebbes who were namesakes: the Tzemach Tzedek, 13th of Nissan 5626 (1866), and the last Rebbe, 3rd of Tammuz 5754 (1994).

Answer (score 2):

128 were the people of *Anasos*, and also the descendants of *Asaf*, who went to *Y'rushalayim*, as listed in Ezra chapter 2.

Answer (score 1):

128 were the soldiers who lived in *Y'rushalayim* ([*N'chemya* 11:14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16518#v=14)).